# How does SMS Premium Voting works technically?

Tags: sms

We are exploring the SMS Premium Voting similar like American Idol/Big Brother etc etc. How does SMS Premium Voting works technically? We are interested in how the data collected as far as I understand the third party company will collect the billing data from each Telco companies. Then it consolidate into a single data mining. Is this the right approach?

Or is it possible to get data from the destination number (the thing is we don't know how does it work so I don't know if this is possible or not).

We are actualy programmer and trying to get this data voting collected centrally or possibly raw data of the SMS but need more information on how does thing works.

I am appreciated your comment or feedback.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One way this works is that the company that owns the number (either telco or a third party with agreements with telco companies) have a service set up so that each SMS received results in an HTTP request to a webserver of the cusomer's choice. Simplified "big brother" has a special page on their web site and the telco companies visit that page once for each SMS posting the SMS content. All filtering and calculations are then completed in the code for that page. Naturally you have to makesure that you ignore any requests from unexpected hosts to avoid voting tampering.

Comment: Hi Cellfish .. ok my understanding is that the telcos send each SMSs to the targeted number which is basically reside on the third party (potentially it can be in one of the telco as you said) and it's using the the HTTP protocol. Am I right? With this sort of method, I guess from the third party company point of view that they are relying on what the telco sent. Correct? From the audit point of few, it needs to check as well then the authenticy (legitimate incoming SMSs). But I guess it will an agreement between the telco and the third party provider. Your thought?

Comment: Yes the 3rd party will rely on whatever HTTP requests the telco makes. And they have to make sure all requests are legitimate which should be easy since allvalid requests would be coming from a few well known IPs owned by the telco. And yes the 3rd party hasto trust the telco to send one request for each SMSnot not more or less.